# SharePoint Online 2013 Email Notifications

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, email, sharepoint-email

I have a list that contains driver's license info for multiple people, and would like to trigger 4 email notifications based on the expiration date - 6 months from expiration, then again at 3 months, 30 days, and final notice when it expires.  Can anyone help in guiding me to create this workflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Microsoft Power Automate (aka Flow). Here is the idea you can create your logic based on:

1. Add a "Recurrence" trigger, Interval and frequency set to your desired values.
2. Create 3 views for your list, first to list all driver's licenses expiring in next 6 months, 2nd in 3 months and last, in 30 days.
   (note: you might be able to achieve it without using the views, but I felt using it will limit the amount of data used)
3. Use 'Get Item' to load your data from your SharePoint list using the above views.
4. Send email notification when your condition matches.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  We don't have that tool...so I would need to accomplish this with a workflow and/or coding.  :-/

Comment: Power Automate is already included if you/ your organization is using O365 E3/ E5 or O365 Pro Plus, you can check if it is available to you. Another option is to create a custom application which will fetch SharePoint data (using CSOM or REST) and send emails as per your logic, you can then schedule it from your existing server with internet connectivity to run periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is that SharePoint designer workflow “Add Time to Date” , “Pause until date” and “send an email” actions.

We can choose the start option as "start the workflow automatically when an item is created" in the workflow settings.

Similar issue for your reference:

[How do you get alerts when items on a list are reaching their expiry date?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/246419/how-do-you-get-alerts-when-items-on-a-list-are-reaching-their-expiry-date)

Comment: ..thank you!  I will try this solution and will report back