# Workflow Item Delete

Tags: 2013, workflow, document-library, designer-workflow, information-lifecycle-management

I have a document library with a lot of documents.  To clean the library up I want to remove all documents that are greater than 3 months. Also I want any document put into the library to be deleted 3 months from the creation date.  I want to create a workflow but not sure how I should do it.  This was my first thought

```
 If creation is less than or equal [today] - 93 
then 
Delete Item
```

Not sure if I am doing this right. Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you get anywhere with this issue?  Did either of the answers help?  Yes, I am fishing for an accept answer, if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

This seems like an opportunity to reuse an [Answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/246289/multiple-information-management-policies-on-content-type-but-just-at-site-leve/246293#246293) that I posted to a similar question.

Just briefly, go in to Document Library Settings>information management policy settings>select Library Based Retention Schedule.

You will then see a screen like you see below.  Your policy is a simple one - select the `Created` date field `39 days` and Action: `Permanently Delete` (or `Move to Recycle Bin`

n.b. documents in the Recycle Bin remain there for a further 30 days by default, before being deleted.  The Recycle Bin is accessible from the Site Collection 'Site Contents' menu.

[image]

You might wish to read in to configuring `Information Management Policy Settings` since these can be defined site-wide on content types OR they can be defined on individual Lists or Document Libraries OR even a combination of the two (with the locally defined policy over-riding the site policy...)

Answer (score 2):

The **Retention and Deletion policies** feature sounds like what you need.

This is a feature that can be activated on a site and used for files and libraries in that site.

A quick search online should find you plenty of guides to get you going.

I don't know if this will act on existing items so other alternatives are to use PowerShell or CSOM to perform a clean up but I would stick to the SharePoint feature until it can't help you any more.